# boost filesystem blocking calls?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, filesystems

Is there any case where the following calls can block? e.g. due to some Windows IO conflicts (i.e. writing to file simultaneously) or something else?

```
recursive_directory_iterator++
file_size
last_write_time
```

I have a function using these which for some reason intermittently has very long execution time (might be something else, I just want make sure the problem doesn't lie here).

Comment: I/O is slow, how long is "very long execution time" ? It might be you're just waiting for the drive to spin, and windows to walk internal structures.

Comment: Consider profiling your executable, the profile should be able to tell you where the time is burnt.

Comment: Unfortunately the environment where this problem occurs it is not possible to profile.